# How can I restore DVD drive operation following most recent Ubuntu r19.04 `apt upgrade`

Tags: apt, vlc, dvd, io

Some time in the last day or two, following one of the recent `apt update`-s the DVD driver on my desktop has stopped working.

- between: 2019-09-15 (UTC) or so
- until:   2019-09-20 (UTC)

After several unsuccessful attempts to understand what happened, I have backtracked a few steps and decided what I need to do '*work forward from here*' and ***restore*** the DVD and replay operations.

Here's my thinking:

- The player should work (it can work)

  - I did work prior to what ever has changed in the software.
- By restoring function, not only will I learn something about that kind of thing, it may help others get past this kind of issue.

  - I have seen earlier problems back with Ubunty 14 and 16 that look similar on stackoverflow/askubntu.
- What ever has happened looks very largely like a regression

  - Nothing has changed in the drive or hardware itself.
  - And the 'target' DVD I chose is one that played fine 8 or 9 days ago.
- If I need to back-out a package or update, so be it.  The best way to findout what it is is to identify today's problem.

**Symptoms**

My layman's view of the problem is that for some reason applications cannot read the DVD content.  `dvdbackup` for example reported that ti cannot find titles.  `Handbrake` and `handbrakeCLI` have similar issues.  They try to read but the interpretation is unintelligible.

Same with VLC no doubt as it just ties and tries and displays a black screen -- Nothing happens.  There are reports of scrambled cells and I/O errors.

You might think a DVD is corrupt.  That's why I picked one I viewed successfully in the recent past.

My aim is to look at what I'd do with a new DVD drive installed.

- What steps would I follow to get a new DVD working?
- What installation errors and problems are showing up now?
- To resolve them if that's practical / feasible.

  - Back out a package or ammeliorate things with alternative or supporting packages that may be not-yet-delivered/installed.

I hope you can help.  Here is the delta between a "before" and "now" scenario where I did a domestic reset and had a cup of tea.

I don't know if the `dmesg` people read these questions, but I'd very much prefer it if `dmesg` output showed the local time so I have a better idea of what is happening and where that was on the time line.  Looking forward to your insights.

Delta experiment ...

**What do we know?**

Tonight ...

1. I took down a Harry Potter DVD that has played on this PC before (some time last week actually).

   - The result is that VLC just shuffles a bit and gives up.
2. So then unloaded the DVD
3. Ran `dmesg > tmp.01`

   - to get the "baseline"
4. Reloaded the DVD into the drive
5. Used the VLC "Play disk" `Media` menu option
6. Allowed the DVD player shuffle and grunt
7. Once that's done, ran `dmesg > tmp.02` again.
8. took a delta (with `diff`) as shown

I apologise for pasting so much here.  I am not clear on what's important and what is just a repeats of the same errors.

**`dmesg` *delta*** ...

```
[60610.254451] scsi_io_completion_action: 2 callbacks suppressed
[60610.254457] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.254460] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.254463] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.254465] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.254467] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[60610.254468] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.254473] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[60610.254474] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.302074] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.302077] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#14 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.302080] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#14 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.302082] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.302084] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.302087] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.338005] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.338008] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.338011] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.338014] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.338015] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.338019] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.373951] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.373954] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.373957] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.373959] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.373961] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.373964] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.406292] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.406295] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#16 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.406298] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#16 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.406301] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.406302] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.406305] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.441955] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.441957] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#17 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.441961] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#17 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.441963] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.441965] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.441968] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.473961] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.473964] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.473967] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.473969] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.473971] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.473974] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.505948] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.505951] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.505954] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.505956] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.505958] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.505961] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.534143] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#20 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.534146] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#20 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.534150] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#20 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.534152] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60610.534154] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60610.534157] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60610.682399] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60610.682403] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60610.682406] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60610.682409] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 fa 35 00 00 01 00
[60610.682411] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 256212 flags 0
[60610.682416] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 64053, async page read
[60622.600135] scsi_io_completion_action: 2 callbacks suppressed
[60622.600142] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.600146] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.600149] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.600152] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.600154] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[60622.600156] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.600161] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[60622.600162] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.632139] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.632142] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.632145] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.632147] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.632149] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.632152] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.664010] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.664013] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.664017] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.664019] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.664021] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.664026] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.696149] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#31 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.696152] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#31 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.696156] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#31 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.696158] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#31 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.696159] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.696163] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.728011] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.728014] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.728017] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.728020] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.728021] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.728025] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.768156] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.768159] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#1 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.768162] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#1 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.768165] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.768166] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.768170] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.800184] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.800187] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#2 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.800190] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#2 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.800192] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.800194] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.800198] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.832250] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.832253] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#3 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.832256] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#3 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.832258] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.832260] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.832264] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60622.860376] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60622.860379] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60622.860383] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60622.860385] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 48 00 00 01 00
[60622.860386] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 23840 flags 0
[60622.860390] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5960, async page read
[60623.004249] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[60623.004252] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[60623.004256] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[60623.004258] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 fa 35 00 00 01 00
[60623.004260] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 256212 flags 0
[60623.004265] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 64053, async page read
```

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't have updates anymore. Please fix the title to reflect your real version.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found the fix for this problem.  Something in last week's update removed or some how hid some or all of the `libdvdcss` package.  The only other activity on the PC last week was some spreadsheets and file editing.  So for now I'm sticking with the regular update theory.

***Fix-it-up***:

In order to be sure everything is installed I removed the key players and reinstalled everything using the [VLC `libdvdcss` build](http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html):

```
sudo apt remove       libdvd-pkg  handbrake-cli  vlc  handbrake
sudo apt install      libdvd-pkg  handbrake-cli  vlc  handbrake
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

*Now* my `dmesg` log is nice and clean again.

I am happy.  I would be curiour however if you know how the `libdvdcss` might have been removed (or crippled) by a package upgrade.  It seems very odd for that to have happened (if indeed that's the vector).

Comment: Nice answer!  Re-installing libdvdcss+dpkg-reconfigure seems to be needed on distributions upgrades too (I had to do this when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.x) ; I guess the post-install of packet `libdvdcss2` is not optimal.